# Command line shows extension "gd" is enabled but WordPress says it isn't. Terminal and phpinfo() showing different PHP versions

Tags: linux, php, php-extensions

`php -v` is showing `5.5.9`
`phpinfo()` is showing `5.6.22`.

WordPress is reporting that I have to enable either `gd` or `imagic` extension in order work with image processing.

The Configure command for `phpinfo()` shows the following:

> './configure'
>   '--cache-file='''/home/subrara/.phpbrew/cache/config.cache''''
>   '--prefix=/home/subrara/.phpbrew/php/php-5.6.22'
>   '--with-config-file-path=/home/subrara/.phpbrew/php/php-5.6.22/etc'
>   '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/home/subrara/.phpbrew/php/php-5.6.22/var/db'
>   '--disable-all' '--enable-session' '--enable-short-tags'
>   '--with-zlib=/usr' '--with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
>   '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd'
>   '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd'
>   '--with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' '--with-curl=/usr'
>   '--enable-json' '--with-gd=shared,/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf'
>   '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr'
>   '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--enable-ftp'
>   '--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-simplexml'
>   '--enable-xml' '--enable-xmlreader' '--enable-xmlwriter' '--with-xsl'
>   '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-opcache' '--enable-bcmath'
>   '--with-bz2=/usr' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-cli' '--enable-ctype'
>   '--enable-dom' '--enable-fileinfo' '--enable-filter' '--enable-shmop'
>   '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg'
>   '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-mhash=/usr'
>   '--with-mcrypt=/usr' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-pcre-regex'
>   '--with-pcre-dir=/usr' '--enable-pdo' '--enable-phar' '--enable-posix'
>   '--with-readline=/usr' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-tokenizer'
>   '--with-openssl=/usr' '--enable-zip'
>   '--with-pear=/home/subrara/.phpbrew/php/php-5.6.22/lib/php'

I didn't understand much of the above.

From terminal (Ubuntu 14.04), when I am running `sudo apt-get install php5-gd`, it says

php5-gd is already the newest version.

As far as I know, the `phpinfo()` version is the one I should consider while running any PHP / WordPress site, and seems like I need to install and enable these extensions for `5.6.22`, but I don't know how!

The output of `php -i | grep 'GD\|ImageMagick'` is:

```
GD Support => enabled
GD Version => 2.1.1-dev
GDM_LANG => en_US
GDMSESSION => ubuntu
_SERVER["GDM_LANG"] => en_US
_SERVER["GDMSESSION"] => ubuntu
```

In this situation, how can I enable `gd` and `imagic` extensions for version 5.6.22?

**EDIT:**
Is this possible to install php7 with required extensions and use it? Will this create any trouble running websites build in localhost?

Comment: It might be that you have both `php-fpm` and `php-cgi` installed, hence the two different versions. Which distro and version are you using?

Comment: output of `lsb_release -a`: `Distributor ID: Ubuntu. Description: Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS. Release: 14.04`